# Issue with making ARSCNView full screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Quick one. I'm having an issue with making an ARSCNView full screen on an iPhone screens over iPhone 10.

[image]

How can In make this ARSCNView completely full screen?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
func makeFullScreen(){
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sceneView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 0),
        sceneView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
        sceneView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
        sceneView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        ])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let sceneView = ARSCNView (frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

Use this above line of code in your view controller class this will take the full screen size for ARSCN View.